# Plugin removed, can't get rid of its data | Control Panel JS

Tags: plugins, control-panel

I was using the [Control Panel JS plugin](https://github.com/doublesecretagency/craft-cpjs), and I entered some erroneous JavaScript that caused it to break the control panel. I then deleted its row in the plug-ins table in the database, and all associated files.

However, when I reinstall it, it finds the old JavaScript and things break again. I cannot figure out where this information is stored.

Comment: If you deleted the external JS file, then it shouldn’t be able to trigger anything, correct? Or did you enter the JS directly into the control panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you entered your explosive JavaScript directly into the control panel (as opposed to an external file), the answer is... complicated.*

---

> ** Disclaimer: I am not a Project Config expert. This advice has not been thoroughly tested. Please tread carefully when editing your database and/or `project.yaml` file.*

---

If you're using [Project Config](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/project-config.html), you'll want to update the value stored in your `config/project.yaml` file. Once you've done that, run `./craft project-config/sync` to update your database accordingly.

If you're *not* using Project Config, then you should be able to just update the database directly. Go to the `projectconfig` table and change this row...

```
|  plugins.cp-js.settings.additionalJs  |  (your explosive js)  |
```

For reference, here's a flowchart to illustrate how the data gets saved...

[image: Plugin Settings Flowchart]

Comment: Yes, I had enter my JS directly into the control panel. 
Brilliant! Your answer solves it. Thanks.